# How do I make this table sortable?

Tags: reactjs

I think this is an easy problem, but I am struggling to understand how to do this since I don't have a class. I am trying to make this table sortable. I want to be able to sort based on the column that is clicked on.
Do I need to add a class? I am very new to ReactJS. Thanks for your help!

```js
function CreateGradeTable(props) {

    return (
        <div>
        <Table>
            <TableHead>
                <TableRow>
                    <TableCell className={props.tHead}>Student</TableCell>
                    <TableCell className={props.tHead}>Course</TableCell>
                    <TableCell className={props.tHead}>Term</TableCell>
                    <TableCell className={props.tHead}>Grade</TableCell>
                    <TableCell className={props.tHead}>Final</TableCell> 
                </TableRow>
            </TableHead>
            <TableBody>
                {props.data.map((gradeDetail, i) => {
                  const {
                    gradeId,
                    courseName,
                    courseId,
                    studentName,
                    studentId,
                    courseTerm,
                    grade,
                    finalGradeForTerm,
                  } = gradeDetail;
                  return (
                      <TableRow
                        key={gradeId}
                        className={`${props.tRow} ${i % 2 !== 0 ? props.striped : ''}`}
                      >
                          <TableCell>
                              <Link to={`/student/${studentId}`}>
                                  <StyledLink>{studentName}</StyledLink>
                              </Link>
                          </TableCell>
                          <TableCell>
                              <Link to={`/course/${courseId}`}>
                                  <StyledLink>{courseName}</StyledLink>
                              </Link>
                          </TableCell>
                          <TableCell align="left">{courseTerm}</TableCell>
                          <TableCell align="left">{grade}</TableCell>
                          <TableCell align="left">{finalGradeForTerm}</TableCell>
                      </TableRow>
                  );
                })}
            </TableBody>
        </Table>
    </div>
    );

        }
```

Comment: seeing that this component gets it's data as props, sorting the data should appropriately be performed on a parent component, you wouldn't *need* as class there either

Comment: Add a function in component `props` which should be invoked on click on heading on column. Through that function you can control the sort order of table data in its parent component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see that you are using Material-UI to display the table. 
You need to use 'TableSortLabel' to display Header. This will also show ascending/descending arrows. 
Then write an onClick handler on TableSortLabel to change state thus triggering re-render.

**See the working example here**

https://codesandbox.io/s/condescending-beaver-q0owe?fontsize=14

```
 <TableBody>

                {

                    props.data.sort(order === 'asc'? ascCompare: desCompare ).map((gradeDetail, i) => {
                  const {
                      grade,
                    courseName,
                    studentName,
                  } = gradeDetail;
                  return (
                      <TableRow
                        key={i}
                      >
                          <TableCell align="left">{grade}</TableCell>
                          <TableCell align="left">{studentName}</TableCell>
                          <TableCell align="left">{courseName}</TableCell>
                      </TableRow>
                  );
                })}
            </TableBody>
```

Comment: This looks amazing!! How do I make it so I can filter on multiple columns at a time?